# Trigger cicd pipeline after merge request accept on master, Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Trying to run some task after merge request get accept (only on master branch).
I am aware of `only: - master -merge_requests` config options, but want to specifically run pipeline only when code get merged in master.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/31296#note_34944784

> ```
> integration-testing:
>   stage: test
>   only:
>     - master
>   script:
>     - ./gradlew clean build asciidoctor
> ```

Another option is to create a webhook

https://gitlab.scm.webanywhere.co.uk/help/user/project/integrations/webhooks.md

If the "Merge request events" is clicked one could trigger a pipeline if a Pull Request gets updated, created or merged.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I am aware of `only  - master `, but this will gonna trigger pipeline even if some creates a merge request too,
I want to trigger the pipeline once the merge request is accepted and I don't wanna use hooks for this task.

Answer (score 0):

More options like this.

```
integration-testing:
  stage: test
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - /release-.+/
```

Complete documentation can be found at [gitlab doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced)